# Rendering a rectangle with multiple textures

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have a 6 vertex rectangle 100x100 in size, this i covered with a 100x100 background image. now i would like to render two "sub textures" on top of it.

lets say i have two sub textures size 20x20 one of then i like to position at x:10 y:10 and the other x:50 and y:50

(these are actually to get used as masks on the background image.)

how should i go with this ? my first thought was to send a uniform vec2 with the position of the two sub textures info the fragment shader, but i cant really figure out how to convert those into texture2d(subtexture, *coordinate*) because texture2d takes 0-1 values. i cant really wrap my head around this, and i hope to get some pointers in what direction i should go.

(this is to be used on OpenGL ES 2.0)

Comment: Do you want the sub textures to become part of the larger texture, or are they really separate objects that lie on top of the "background" rectangle?

Comment: it should become part, because actually what i need to do is use the sub textures to mask the large texture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then I think what you're really looking for is how to update a texture.  In you case, the simplest method may be to use [`glTexSubImage2D`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexSubImage2D.xml).  The following will do what you ask in your original post

```
glTexSubImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 10, 10, 20, 20, <format>, <type>, <subimage1> );
glTexSubImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 50, 50, 20, 20, <format>, <type>, <subimage2> );
```

where `<format>`, and `<type>` describe the pixels in the sub-texture stored at `<subimage*>`.  There are quite a lot of additional answers in other questions; just search for glTexSubImage2D.

A more complex method (for when things aren't as simple as your problem) is to use framebuffer objects to render to textures (have search for that one too, if you need).